# How is the size of the StatusBar (in the Toolbar) set?

Tags: codenameone

In my app, on iphone as well as in the iPhoneX skin on the simulator, the size of StatusBar (inside the Toolbar) is for some reason too small/thin, so the title of the Form is shown partially hidden by the iPhoneX notch.

I've tried to understand how to fix this, but I simply can't figure out how the size of the StatusBar is set. I don't change the size of the StatusBar UIID in my css file, nor in my code and yet it is smaller than if I create a fresh Hello World example with the iPhoneX.skin.

I first thought it could be the SafeArea which changed the size, but it doesn't seem so. Then I thought the default theme (or the values of the Default UIID in the css) could change the size, but it doesn't seem to be that either. I probably miss something obvious, but I'm stuck so any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS. I could of course force the size of the StatusBar in css myself, but then I'm not sure it will work on the various devices, so I prefer rely on the default value defined by CN1.

Answer (score 0):

The `StatusBar` UIID is defined internally and is generally hard coded to a value that fits for most themes. This very much depends on the padding in your `Title` UIID which is often large and works in tandem with the status bar. Assuming your title has 0 padding you might need more padding to the `StatusBar`.

Assuming you're using CSS you can use something like:

```css
@media platform-ios {
    StatusBar {
        padding: 7mm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, my question is not actually about how to set it, but to understand how/why it changes to a wrong value in my app. The margin of StatusBar is somehow changed to 2 and padding to 3 (pixels) and I just can’t figure how/where it happens. But it sounds from your answer like it should not be changed by CN1 except for the values set by the theme (the iOS7Theme.res file I assume)? I’ve also checked the .res file in the Designer to and the StatusBar does not Derive from anything else.

Comment: Are you using CSS or the Designer?
Did you define a global default that might impact the default usage of millimeters as the unit type?

Comment: I use css. But I checked the .res with Designer. I have indeed defined Default in css but it doesn’t define padding/margin. I was not aware there is a way to change the default usage of millimeters as unit type, what could make that happen?

Comment: The base iOS native theme defines the default to millimeters. I don't think that's changeable but maybe there's a bug in the loading that caused the theme to load partially. Do you see anything in the console?

Comment: I don't see any obvious issues in the output log. I get this: "Retina Scale: 2.0
Using stateful mode. Use -help flag to see options for new stateless mode.
Updating merge file /Users/user/NetBeansProjects/myapp/target/css/theme.css.merged
Compiling /Users/user/NetBeansProjects/myapp/target/css/theme.css.merged to /Users/user/NetBeansProjects/myapp/src/theme.res
File has not changed since last compile." I found somewhere in the code that the styles initialize to the same 2 and 3 I mentioned above. Is there a way I could debug to understand where the theme style is being changed?

Comment: UIManager is where the theme is applied to the UI. If you can extract a test case that shows this consistently I'd like to see that.